# Google Autocomplete React component resetting state after place is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using the [Google Autocomplete](https://github.com/ErrorPro/react-google-autocomplete) component and when `onPlaceSelected` I am saving the place into a state array (`input`) of the parent component. However, whenever a place is selected the previous value is set to an empty array and then adds the newly selected place, instead of adding it to the existing array. I am thinking it has something to do with refs (since I think the component uses these), but I'm not sure how to start fixing it, since I am not very experienced in using refs. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

High Level Example:

```js
1. inputs = [place1];
2. onPlaceSelected={(place2) => {
          console.log(inputs); // prints empty array
          addInput(place2);
}}
4. input = [place2]; // should be input = [place1, place2]

// addInput basically does this
function addInput(place) {
          setInputs[...inputs, place]l;
}
```

This is my actual code:

```js
// Autocomplete component
<Autocomplete
  id="address"
  name="address"
  className="side-panel__form__input"
  placeholder="Enter an address"
  onPlaceSelected={(place, inputRef, autocomplete) => {
    console.log("inputs", inputs); // passed in props from parent component state
    // inputs array should have elements inside but is empty here, not sure why
    console.log("place", place);
    console.log("inputRef", inputRef);
    console.log("autocomplete", autocomplete);
    handleAddPlace(place);
  }}
  options={{
    types: ["address"],
    componentRestrictions: { country: "us" },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of the problem without seeing the full code, including the parent component, but I do have a guess.

I assume that:

- The parent component defines `inputs` state: `const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([])`
- `handleAddPlace` looks something like
  this: `const handleAddPlace = (place) => setState([...inputs, place])`

This is where the problem lies: `handleAddPlace` is a closure which seems to be getting "closes" around a stale value of `inputs`. If `handleAddPlace` does not get redefined when `inputs` changes, it will remain closed around original value of `inputs`, which later becomes stale. Every time you call `handleAddPlace`, `inputs` is `[]`.

There are a couple of ways in which this can be fixed:

**Option 1**: use the setState callback to update `inputs`

```
const handleAddPlace = (place) => setState(inputs => [...inputs, place])
```

This ensures that the latest value of `inputs` is used.

**Option 2**: use a ref to `inputs`
If the above option is not feasible, you can use a ref to ensure that you always operate on the current value of `inputs`.

```
const inputsRef = useRef(inputs)
const handleAddPlace = (place) => setState([...inputsRef.current, place])
```

`inputsRef.current` will always resolve to the latest value of `inputs`, and cannot become stale.

For further reading, see [Dmitri Pavlutin's blog post](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). It discusses several common pitfalls involving stale closures in React components.